# Whats wrong with one statement(Error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this statement:

```
.Cells(14, 22).Value = "=(" & dblSafety & "+V76*AP28)" & "/AP46"
```

dblSafety has double as type and the value: 10779717,8414514

It writes a Formula in a Cell. The Formula should look like this:

=(10779717,8414514 + V76 * AP28) / AP46

But i get the Error with the Number 1004. I have the german version so it says:

"Anwendungs- oder Objektdefinierter Fehler"

I think in english it would be:

"Application-defined or Object-defined error"

I dont understand why there is an error. If dblSafety is 0 then there is no error. Is the Number to big?

Any Help is appreciated

*edit*
If I convert the variable to a long type I dont get any errors, but I need the decimal part.

Comment: what is type of `dblSafety` variable? Variant, Double, String?

Comment: double, I have tried this too: cstr(dblSafety) but I get the same error

Comment: try .Cells(14, 22).Formula = ...

Comment: If i write it like this: .Cells(14, 22).Formula = "(" & dblSafety & "+V76*AP28)" & "/AP46" I dont get an error. But if i write this: .Cells(14, 22).Formula = "=(" & dblSafety & "+V76*AP28)" & "/AP46" i get the same error

Comment: Does it work if dblSafety does not contain a decimal part?

Comment: In cases you want to check if the number is too big, use smaller numbers for the example. Or a simpler formula until you find whats wrong

Comment: If I convert it to long It works so the problem is because of the decimal part. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to substitute explicitly the comma `,` with a decimal point `.` before concatenating to your formula.

Excel and VBA are not as locale-friendly as they ought to be: the implicit `CStr` is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with: replace(dblSafety, "," , ".")